How to resolve RECAPTCHA token expired and invalid error?
Message is ==>The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired.
Eror is The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired.
[firebase_auth/invalid-verification-id] The verification ID or SMS code is invalid.
I have tried to get OTP from firebase for my web application and ends with this error
"[firebase_auth/invalid-verification-id] The verification ID or SMS code is invalid."
"Message is ==>The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired.
Eror is The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired."
But in firebase authentication , my app is added to the authorized domains under phone authentication.
